# Getting rid of parts of the polygon

Tags: polygon, clip

I have thousand of polygons which have parts in it which I want to get rid of. How do I do that with QGIS not with POSTGIS? The picture below shows an example. I want to get rid of the parts which I marked red.

[image]

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried v.generalize from GRASS. However, Im not so familiar with SQL statements. So Im hoping that somebody knows how to do it with that tool or has another alternative...

Comment: Have you any rules, which parts should be removed, and which not? Also, if you already tried something, add it to your question including the expression you used - if that is your favorable way of editing the data.

Comment: It is not my favourable way and I didnt use any expression yet because I dont really know SQL. I would take any solution which works. I want everything gone which looks almost like a line. I would say I width of 1.5 meter or so.